# Проблемы с подключением к БД

Tags: php, mysql

Салют! 
Не могу понять что происходит не так с подключением к базе данных.
Подключаюсь под админом.

**Код подключения:**

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'forum';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host = $host; dbname = $db; charset=$charset";
$opt = [
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES =>false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM catalogs;');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
echo $row['name'] . "\n";
}
```

**После запуска, получаю ошибку**:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in E:\nginx\html\code\bd\connect-db.php:35 Stack trace: #0 E:\nginx\html\code\bd\connect-db.php(35): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM c...') #1 {main} thrown in E:\nginx\html\code\bd\connect-db.php on line 35

Comment: После `catalogs` точку с запятой уберите.
так же почитайте про подготовленные запросы.

Comment: Из $dsn удалите все пробелы которые у вас там нарисованы.

Comment: вы php myadmin под этим пользователем можете войти? или из консоли mysql -u root пробовали? что пишет

Comment: @DantheHat, точка с запятой там не мешает, и по феншую должна там быть.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский точно? надо почитать будет повнимательнее про пдо...

Comment: @DantheHat, она не обязательна, это да, но и не мешает ничему. Это же просто запрос к mysql. Я вообще ставлю всегда, потому что мне нравится, как выглядит этот символ: "точка с запятой".

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде SQL запрос можно как с запятой, так и без.

В строке dsn пробелы можно использовать! Только кроме секции dbname, тут нельзя пробел ни перед знаком равно, ни после. Вот так работает: `"mysql: host = $host; dbname=$db; charset = $charset"`. Не знаю почему, могу лишь предположить, что данная строка распарсивается регуляркой или explode() и где-то косяк. Поэтому следует быть более осторожным, чтобы запариться на такой мелочи - не делайте лишние пробелы, мы не в Ворде редактируем текст.

Данный код работает, проверил на своем компе:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'forum';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql: host = $host; dbname=$db; charset = $charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM catalogs LIMIT 20;');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['name'] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

посмотрите примеры подключения
Уберите лишние пробелы и, возможно, поставьте пробел после "mysql:"